# Entity Framework ICollection to List

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do something like this:

```
 List<Department> t = db.Employees
        .Where(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(12345))
        .Where(e => e.Departments.Any(d => d.IsActive.Equals(true)))
        .Select(e => e.Departments);
```

But it gives me an error telling me that can't implicitly convert from `IQueryable<ICollection<Department>> to List<Department>`.

My Linq is a bit rusty. What is the right way to bring this down to the `List<Department>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a queryable collection of a collection of departments (note the plural `e.Departments`).  As a result, you can use `.SelectMany()` to flatten your collection and then resolve the IQueryable with `.ToList()`.

```
List<Department> t = db.Employees
    .Where(e => e.CompanyId.Equals(12345))
    .Where(e => e.Departments.Any(d => d.IsActive.Equals(true)))
    .SelectMany(e => e.Departments).ToList();
```